# Blowfish encryption extremely slow on mobile for 3 mb file

Tags: android, encryption, blowfish

I was rather surprised at how incredibly slow the encryption process is on Android using the Blowfish encryption from Bouncy Castle. A 3 mb file took over 3 minutes. Is there some other algorithm that is extremely fast? I can live with less reliable security. Here's the code. Everything is done in memory. No files.

```
private BufferedBlockCipher cipher;
private KeyParameter key;

public Encryption(byte[] key)
{
  try
  {
    BlowfishEngine blowfishEngine = new BlowfishEngine();
    CBCBlockCipher cbcBlockCipher = new CBCBlockCipher(blowfishEngine);

    cipher = new org.spongycastle.crypto.modes.PaddedBlockCipher(cbcBlockCipher);

    this.key = new KeyParameter(key);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  }
}

public Encryption(String key)
{
  this(key.getBytes());
}

public synchronized byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data) throws CryptoException
{
  try
  {
    if (data == null || data.length == 0)
    {
      return new byte[0];
    }

    cipher.init(true, key);
    return CallCipher(data);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return null;
  }
}

private byte[] CallCipher(byte[] data) throws CryptoException
{
  try
  {
    int size = cipher.getOutputSize(data.length);
    byte[] result = new byte[size];
    int olen = cipher.processBytes(data, 0, data.length, result, 0);
    olen += cipher.doFinal(result, olen);

    if (olen < size)
    {
      byte[] tmp = new byte[olen];
      System.arraycopy(result, 0, tmp, 0, olen);
      result = tmp;
    }

    return result;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: You didn't post your code. Blowfish shouldn't be that slow when used correctly. Either BC's implementation sucks, or you're using it in a inefficient way. And why did you choose blowfish and not AES? AES is strong and fast.

Comment: OK, I added the code above. I chose Blowfish simply because it has a good reputation for security and specs show it fast. Maybe you're right and BC's implementation sucks.

Comment: I tried out this mobile app and it uses AES. It encrypted a 3 mb file in a few seconds: http://goo.gl/fcOjy  So clearly something is amiss.

Comment: Have you tried encrypting smaller chunks, such as 4KiB? Multiple 3MB allocations could be problematic on a memory constraint device? And have you tried AES? I'd expect the AES implementation to be optimized, since it's the standard cipher, whereas blowfish is rather exotic.

Comment: Are you saying that instead of having a 3 mb array, to use a 4 kb array instead and then encode 4 kb at a time? Are you suggesting that loading a 3 mb file into memory is the problem due to Android's performance? You could be right. Before I switch to another algorithm like AES, I'll try your first suggestion on breaking it up into smaller chunks.

Comment: I don't program for android, so I don't know what the performance impact of those allocations is. On a PC it wouldn't be expensive enough to explain 3 mins for 3 MB.

Comment: You might try replacing `cipher.processBytes` with a simply array copy. No cipher is faster than the identity permutation. Just for timing of course.

Answer (score 0):

Blowfish is actually a fast cipher. Even with slowness of Java it should give some Mb/sec.
Most likely the problem is in how you use it (for instance, writing to file in 8-byte blocks). Or, how BouncyCastle team is coded it.
Try AES-128, it should be faster.
And, the fastest solution (and much less secure) is RC4.

Comment: From what I read, Blowfish is fast but that is just a relative term. The slow encryption doesn't have anything to do with a file. The entire data is stored in a byte array and manipulated in memory. Maybe Bouncy Castle's implementatin happens to be slow, although I serously doubt it considering it is used extensively in both mobile and non-mobile apps.

Comment: You can simply check with profiler which part of the code is the slowest.